# Correct way to remove -noframemerging option

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I noticed that when I start up IE in SeleniumWebdriver with

```
var ieoptions = new InternetExplorerOptions()
{
    EnablePersistentHover = false,
    EnsureCleanSession = true,
    RequireWindowFocus = true,
};
```

I have this -noframemerging flag in my IE command line. I don't want this flag
After some digging I managed to find that I can seemingly take it out by adding

```
 ForceCreateProcessApi = true,
 BrowserCommandLineArguments = "-framemerging"
```

but that would only work with an accompanying regedit for

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main = 0
```

I'd prefer to keep my IE working in the same way in manual and automated tests - i.e. not messing about with the number of processes in play. So is there an easier solution available here? I find it hard to understand why the -noframemerging flag is turned on by IEServerDriver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no easier solution here. `IEDriverServer.exe` does nothing to modify the command line used to launch IE. If a switch is being added to the command line, it's being done by the Windows `IELaunchURL` API, which is what the driver uses by default to launch the browser to be able to accommodate Protected Mode. The way to have "control" over what command line is used is with the `CreateProcess`API, and you've already discovered how to make the driver do that. "Control" is deliberately put in scare quotes here because unfortunately, `CreateProcess` isn't reliable with IE unless you use the registry entry. Moreover, IE doesn't have the concept of user profiles, and your desire to maintain the browser's behavior for your non-WebDriver use is exactly why the driver doesn't set registry entries for you.